# How do I pass the selected list to a lightning component via URLFOR

Tags: lightning, list-view, urlfor

You can now launch a lightning component from a list view button using the URLFOR() function with a lightning component that implements the lightning:isUrlAddressable interface. As part of the URLFOR() function, you can pass a parameter in the third argument. What I haven't figured out is how to pass the list of selected records.

```
{!URLFOR("lightning/cmp/c__MyComponent", null, ??? )}
```

or, is there another way in the component to get those records?

Comment: Why don't you gather the list of ids and use that URLFOR. Something like this `{!URLFOR("lightning/cmp/c__MyComponent",null,[lstRecordIds=recordIds])}`. And use this list of recordids in your component.

Comment: It doesn't accept recordIds. Says "Field recordIds does not exist".

Comment: Also tried {!URLFOR("lightning/cmp/c__addMarkedCompanies", null, [sendIds=
({!GETRECORDIDS( $ObjectType.Account )}).toString()
)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GETRECORDIDS()` does not seem to work with `URLFOR` calling a lightning component.

There is an alternative using a Visualforce page that in turn calls the lightning component, here is the procedure for account list view:

1. Create a visualforce page of type standard list controller
2. In visualforce constructor method, retrieve list of selected records in list view using `ApexPages.StandardSetController getSelected()` method and build a comma separated string `accIds` of the account ids selected in listview
3. Define an apex method in `<apex:page>` action that returns a `pageReference` to redirect to lightning component URL similar to this `/lightning/cmp/c__yourAuraComponentName?c__auraAttributeName='+accIds`
4. Then create a custom button of type list and select the visualforce page as content source
5. Create lightning component that implements `lightning:isUrlAddressable` , having an attribute to store the acccount ids `auraAttributeName` and init handler method
6. In lightning component controller JS init method, retrieve `pageReference` attribute from `v.pageReference` and get list of account ids from `myPageRef.state.c__auraAttributeName`
7. Perform any other processing in lightning component

**For detailed sample code refer to my [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/289963/56063) to a similar question**

Comment: Is there really no better way to call a lightning component from a list view?

Comment: @BrianMiller I agree that the visualforce solution is not the ideal way but could not find any better solution. Hope something simpler will be supported soon

Comment: This is a great solution in the meantime - thank you for sharing here and in the linked answer!