# How do I add an action similar to edit and delete to the list view for each and every record?

Tags: list-view, lightninglistview

[image]

How to add an action inside the yellow box?
Is this something that can be done or not?

Comment: Take a look here https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/09/take-the-first-steps-ways-you-can-replace-javascript-buttons.html There is similar thing implemented here, check this section `Alternative: Custom Visualforce Buttons`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not something that can be done. The [Actions in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.actions_in_lex.htm&type=5) mention the following

> **List view items** support only specific standard actions, like Edit, Delete, or Change Owner.

**What you are able to change, is the List View actions themselves (buttons at top right of list view)**

[image]

> Custom buttons, list view actions, and certain standard buttons are supported on all list views, except Recently Viewed. To have a custom button appear on a list view, add the button to the object’s List View search layout.

You can create a [Quick Action](https://salesforceben.com/mass-update-records-in-salesforce-using-quick-actions-in-list-views/) with an action type of `Update Record`. That will update whatever records you select in your given list view.

If you need more complex processing/logic, you can also look at examples of passing selected record(s) in the list view to a button that calls a [flow](https://wiki.sfxd.org/books/cool-links-stuff/page/how-to-check-off-records-on-a-list-view-and-pass-them-all-to-a-flow-%28button%29) or a [VF page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289264/get-selected-records-from-lightning-list-view-custom-button-url-addressable).

In terms of adding your Quick Action or custom button, you add it to the available buttons for list view within the object.

`Setup --> Object Manager --> your object --> Search Layouts for Salesforce Classic --> Edit "List View" layout`

[image]