# Custom Button or Link in List View Rows

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, list-view, quickaction

In a Lightning Experience app, in a list view, can I add a custom action button/link to the action menu (highlighted below):

[image]

This button/link will provide a sort of checkout mechanism that changes the owner id from the object to the current user, then opens a custom LWC for them to edit details related to the item.

Alternatively, a separate link/button in its own column (not underneath the Actions dropdown menu) would be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot customize the list view item's actions. [Actions in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.actions_in_lex.htm&type=5) mention this:

> List view items support only specific standard actions, like Edit,
> Delete, or Change Owner.

There's a couple lowly voted ideas asking for this ability:

- [Custom actions on List view items](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeowUAB/custom-actions-on-list-view-items)
- [Actions on List View Items for custom buttons](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfzqUAB/actions-on-list-view-items-for-custom-buttons)

**You can customize the buttons that display on the list view itself.** This would allow you to select one (or multiple) records from the list view and perform an update action on them (quick action) or pass the record ids to a flow (through URL button) or VF page.

1. Create a [quick action](https://www.salesforceben.com/mass-update-records-in-salesforce-using-quick-actions-in-list-views/) of the type `Update Record`.
2. Add it to the list view layout

`Setup --> Object Manager --> Your Object --> Search layouts for Salesforce Classic --> Edit "List View" layout`

[image]

If you need more complex logic to be initiated by the button (multiple screens) or to leverage a LWC, you'd have to look at utilizing it within a [Flow](https://medium.com/usetheforce/using-flow-builder-to-update-selected-list-view-records-2c94ae3bd95c) or a [VF page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289264/get-selected-records-from-lightning-list-view-custom-button-url-addressable) in a [List Button](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_buttons_links) that has `Display Checkboxes (for Multi-Record Selection` enabled.

[image]